# Flex-shrink not working even when i have some extra space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make my image slider responsive but it is not working.
I can try it with `media query` but that's a lot of code and I don't think it is efficient. It is showing some white-space but it is still not working. I also looked at another question on stack overflow and it said i should have white-space. In my case 'flex-shrink' doesn't seem to work.

```css
.recipes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
}

.recipes h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--section-heading);
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.btns-image-slider label[for] {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 200ms background-color;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btns-image-slider label[for]:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: none;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 2;
}

.container input {
  display: none;
}

#r1:checked~.images {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#r2:checked~.images {
  transform: translateX(-800px);
}

#r3:checked~.images {
  transform: translateX(-1600px);
}

#r4:checked~.images {
  transform: translateX(-2400px);
}

#r5:checked~.images {
  transform: translateX(-3200px);
}

.images {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 2400px;
  height: 600px;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.images a {
  position: relative;
}

.images a:hover::after {
  content: url(../images/overlay-6.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-70%, -49.55%);
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.services>h1 {
  font-family: var(--section-heading);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="recipes">
  <h1>Popular recipes</h1>
  <div class="container">

    <input type="radio" name="r" checked id="r1">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">


    <div class="images">

      <a href="images/1.png"><img src="images/slide1.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/slide2.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/slide3.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/slide4.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/slide5.jpg"></a>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <div class="btns-image-slider">
      <label for="r1"></label>
      <label for="r2"></label>
      <label for="r3"></label>
      <label for="r4"></label>
      <label for="r5"></label>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to size your elements, `width` or `min-width` will do aside `flex-shrink`  if also needed. height can be remove most of the time, let the browser manage it.

`<a>` holds image and is a direct child of `.images` with a hudge width, but only a third of it is shown, so `<a>` needs to be `33.33%` of width (or 2400px/3).

If your images have different ratio, `object-fit` can also help (if all image have the same size and are not shrinked/expanded , don't mind it

possible example from your code with image of different ratio to show o`bject-fit` use

```css
.recipes{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
}

.recipes h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--section-heading);
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.btns-image-slider label[for]{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 200ms background-color;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btns-image-slider label[for]:hover{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: none;
}


.container{
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 2;
}



.container input{
  display: none;
}

#r1:checked ~ .images{
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#r2:checked ~ .images{
  transform: translateX(-800px);
}

#r3:checked ~ .images{
  transform: translateX(-1600px);
}

#r4:checked ~ .images{
  transform: translateX(-2400px);
}

#r5:checked ~ .images{
  transform: translateX(-3200px);
}

.images{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 2400px;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1000ms; 
}

.center{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.images a{
  position: relative;
  min-width:33.33%;
}

.images a img {width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover}
.images a:hover::after{
  content: url(../images/overlay-6.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-70%,-49.55%);
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}



@keyframes appear {
  from{
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


.services > h1{
  font-family: var(--section-heading);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="recipes">
  <h1>Popular recipes</h1>
  <div class="container">

    <input type="radio" name="r" checked id="r1">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">


    <div class="images">

      <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x200/456&text=slide1.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x250/ac8&text=images/slide2.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x230/f90&text=images/slide3.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x180/cc5&text=images/slide4.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x200/bee&text=images/slide5.jpg"></a>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <div class="btns-image-slider">
      <label for="r1"></label>
      <label for="r2"></label>
      <label for="r3"></label>
      <label for="r4"></label>
      <label for="r5"></label>
    </div>

</section>
```

you could also turn 2400px into 300% and use percentage else where (width, translate() ... , so then you can use also percentage for container instead 800px with eventually a max-width and min-width in pixel to avoid it to shrink or grow too much.

Comment: I tried your code but it is not responsive it was the whole point of my question. I wanted it to shrink its size when used flex-shrink :(

Comment: @Self-Coder So read what's underneath the snippet, it's all about resizing according to the window' size . use % instead fixed pixel values. I think you can do it yourself.